# how can the coordinates for a revit fabricationpart be obtained with the revit api

Tags: revit-api

I need to obtain the coordinates for Revit MEP FabricationParts.
All of the elements I get do have a location property but not all of them have either a LocationPoint or a LocationCurve. More specific, only for Pipe elements am I able to get XYZ values through the LocationCurve. Elements such as Threadolet, Elbow, Weld and Fishmouth don't have either a LocationPoint or a LocationCurve.

Using Revit 2024.2

I written some test code that loops over the FabricationParts in a project file, tries to get XYZ values and shows the results in a dialog box.

[Result of the code trying to get XYZ values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCpvB.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for finding the location of `FabricationParts` as I have outlined in detail below.

For your application with OLets, ThreadOLets and Elbows, I most often use the connectors to determine location. For Olets, I use the connector that connects to the main pipe as its insertion point, since that is technically where the element was inserted:

```cs
    Connector insertionPointConnector = OLet.ConnectorManager
        .Connectors
        .OfType<Connector>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectorType == ConnectorType.Curve);
    
    XYZ insertionPoint = insertionPointConnector?.Origin;
```

Since their connectors are atypical in that they do not connect to another connector, but instead a curve, you need to get the one that is `ConnectorType.Curve`.

For welds, elbows and other inline elements, you can similarly I use the connectors and get their origins. If you want the center of the element, you can use vector math to calculate that using the connector's direction and location. The direction that the connector points is the `BasisZ` property of the Connector's `CoordinateSystem`.

```cs
    XYZ connectorDirection = insertionPointConnector?.CoordinateSystem.BasisZ;
```

#### Detailed Overview of Various Approaches

Below I built sample commands illustrate each apporach by drawing a 6" vertical line at each "insertion point" as calculated. The snippet below was used to draw those lines. Depending on your application, you may want to do something similar to ensure that you are consistently getting the location that makes the most sense for you application.

```cs
public static class Drawing
{
    public static void DrawVerticalLine(this XYZ pt, Document document, double length)
    {
        var plane = Plane.CreateByNormalAndOrigin(XYZ.BasisY, pt);
        var sketchPlane = SketchPlane.Create(document, plane);
        var insertionPointVisual = Line.CreateBound(pt, pt + (length * XYZ.BasisZ));
        document.Create.NewModelCurve(insertionPointVisual, sketchPlane);
    }
}

// in the actual IExternalCommand
public override Result Execute()
{
    var fabricationParts = UiDoc.Selection.GetElementIds()
        .Select(x => Doc.GetElement(x))
        .OfType<FabricationPart>()
        .ToList();

    var insertionPoints = fabricationParts
        .Select(x => getByBBoxCenter(x))
        .ToList();

    using (var t = new Transaction(Doc, "Show Centers"))
    {
        t.Start();
        foreach (var pt in insertionPoints)
        {
            pt.DrawVerticalLine(Doc, 0.5);
        }
        t.Commit();
    }

    return Result.Succeeded;
}
```

##### Use the `Connectors` via `ConnectorManager.Connectors` property to calculate a center

Things to consider:

- Connectors have different `ConnectorTypes` which help you identify which connector you are looking at
- They have a location that can be obtained via the `Origin` property
- They have a direction that can be obtained via the `CoordinateSystem.BasisZ` property
- They are fairly consistent and reliably exist in `FabricationParts`
- Different element types will have different numbers of connectors of varying types, and this can lead to additional complexity

```cs
private static XYZ getCenterByConnectors(FabricationPart part)
{
    var connectors = part.ConnectorManager.Connectors.OfType<Connector>().ToList();

    var end1 = connectors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectorType == ConnectorType.End);
    var end2 = connectors.LastOrDefault(x => x.ConnectorType == ConnectorType.End);

    var connector1Direction = end1.CoordinateSystem.BasisZ;
    var connector2Direction = end2.CoordinateSystem.BasisZ;

    var areParallel = connector1Direction
        .CrossProduct(connector2Direction)
        .IsAlmostEqualTo(XYZ.Zero);

    if (areParallel)
        return (end1.Origin + end2.Origin) / 2.0; // midpoint formula

    // for elbows, tees, crosses, etc., we want the intersection of the connectors
    // since the midpoint might not be at the center
    var line1 = Line.CreateUnbound(end1.Origin, end1.CoordinateSystem.BasisZ);
    var line2 = Line.CreateUnbound(end2.Origin, end2.CoordinateSystem.BasisZ);
    var intersection = line1.Intersect(line2, out var resultArray);

    var elbowCenterByIntersection = resultArray.get_Item(0).XYZPoint;

    return elbowCenterByIntersection;
}
```

[image: Elbow Center by Connectors]
[image: Sample Spool by Connectors]

##### Using the first `Connector` via the `ConnectorManager.Connectors` property

- Connectors are not ordered and order is not guaranteed, so you need to sort them by something that will yield consistent results. You can use the ID property or sort them geometrically.
- You may want certain logic to pick the specific `ConnectorType` for your use case

```cs
private XYZ getInsertionPointByFirst(FabricationPart part)
{
    var connectors = part.ConnectorManager.Connectors.OfType<Connector>().ToList();

    // must be sorted, otherwise this will have unpredictable results,
    // since the connector sort order is not guaranteed
    var end1 = connectors.OrderBy(x => x.Id) 
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectorType == ConnectorType.End);

    return end1.Origin;
}
```

[image: Sample Spool by First End Connector]

##### Using the `BoundingBox` via the `get_BoundingBox()` method

- Bounding boxes are view dependent, so you will get different results in different views
- For things like Elbows and OLets, this might not be the desired "center" of the element

```cs
private XYZ getByBBoxCenter(FabricationPart part)
{
    var bbox = part.get_BoundingBox(UiDoc.ActiveView);

    XYZ bboxCenter = (bbox.Max + bbox.Min) / 2.0;

    return bboxCenter;
}
```

[image: Elbow Center by BBox Center]
[image: Sample Spool by BBox Center]

##### Evaluating all the geometry of the object to calculate the centroid

I'm not going to provide an example of this one, since it can get very complex. This approach can also be slow, since you will potentially have to look at a lot of lines, faces, points, etc. to evaluate a centroid.

##### Using the `Location` property

This will not work consistently for your case, as you pointed out in your question, but I am including it for completeness.

- Differing inheritted types `LocationPoint` and `LocationCurve` make you have to use different approaches for calulating the location.
- Not always fully populated as stated above

Comment: Great pointer! Thanks.

Comment: Per your question in the comments to Jeremy's answer, the connector midpoint and centroid could be different. The reason for this is that the connectors do not have to be at the extents of the element. If you are looking for the centroid, or dead center, I would go with the cooresponding of Jeremy's approach.

Comment: @bootsch, I updated my answer to add some clarity. I am worry that your approach will generate unpredictable results, since the **Connector ordering is not consistent, even for the same fabrication part on subsequent runs.** This means that if you just take the first connector without sorting, your "insertion point" may be different for the same element in different command executions. This might be okay in your application, but I wanted to point it out in case it could cause any issues.

Comment: Very detailed answer! @egeer Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The solution I end up with is a bit different from the answer given by egeer.
I ended up getting a Connector for each element (the ones without a LocationCurve or LocationPoint).

Here's the code in VB.

```
    Dim insertionPointConnector As Connector = CType(e, FabricationPart).ConnectorManager.Connectors.OfType(Of Connector).FirstOrDefault()
    Dim elementOrigin as XYZ = Connector.insertionPointConnector.Origin
```

'e' is of type Element

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

- Use the `Location` property
- Retrieve the element [`Geometry` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/d8a55a5b-2a69-d5ab-3e1f-6cf1ee43c8ec.htm), e.g., calculate the centroid of all the vertices
- Use the element [`BoundingBox` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/def2f9f2-b23a-bcea-43a3-e6de41b014c8.htm), e.g., calculate its midpoint

Comment: Would the calculation of either the centroid or the midpoint give the same result as the Origin retrieved in the method using a Connector.?